# How do I check if a variable is equal to a string or an int?

Tags: c#

For example, lets say I have and int called input. And then I get input for it. Like this:

```
input = Console.ReadLine();
```

But when the user gets prompted, input is a string, and then it gets an error and crashes the program. How do I check if a string was entered for input?

Is there an option for it like `if (input.equals(string))` or something like that?

EDIT: I tried doing the TryParse but I think I'm doing it wrong. I posted the code below

```
    string numberOne;
    string numberTwo;
    double answer;
    string operand;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number");
    numberOne = Console.ReadLine();
    if (double.TryParse(numberOne, out double value))
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(numberOne);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Non integer entered. Please enter a valid number.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the operator");
    operand = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number");
    numberTwo = Console.ReadLine();
    if (double.TryParse(numberTwo, out double value2))
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(numberTwo);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Non integer entered. Please enter a valid number.");
    }




    switch(operand)
    {
        case "+":
            answer = numberOne + numberTwo;
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + answer);
            break;

        case "-":
            answer = numberOne - numberTwo;
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + answer);
            break;

        case "*":
            answer = numberOne * numberTwo;
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + answer);
            break;

        case "/":
            answer = numberOne / numberTwo;
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + answer);
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid operator such as +, -, *, or /");
            break;



    }
```

Comment: You should get in the habit today of reading the documentation; as the documentation for `ReadLine` notes, it *always* returns a string.

Comment: @killakrab really? You have a program that contains `int input = Console.ReadLine();` and it compiles, and it runs, and you only get an error after the user has typed something and hit enter?  Wow.

Comment: Are you asking the question explicitly for Console.ReadLine or was that just an example and this is a more general question?

Comment: @Mike Nakis I'm learning c# right now and am trying to make a simple calculator that doesn't crash when a string is entered instead of an integer.

Comment: See my answer below please. It handles multiple wrong input, plus the correct syntax for older versions of C#, one of which you seemingly use.

Comment: The code you wrote is wrong in a great many ways. Can you say what you believe `Covert.ToInt32` does?  Now read the documentation for it. Can you now explain what it actually does? Can you explain why you are parsing the string as double and then converting to int rather than parsing as int in the first place?

Comment: You seem to have some very wrong beliefs about data types. A string containing digits is still a string; make sure that is clear, because without understanding that, nothing is going to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.Readline() always returns a string, however you can do this to check if an integer is inputed and continue asking for correct type of input until user delivers it.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int parsed;
while (!int.TryParse(input, out parsed))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number!");
     input = Console.ReadLine();
}

//do something with parsed
```

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine` always returns a `string`. It's doesn't return differently typed things based the content read from console. It's your job to decide if the value entered matches your requirements (in this case it should be something that can be parsed to an int).

You can use `int.TryParse` to try parsing a string as `int` without it throwing an exception when parsing fails.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if(int.TryParse(input, out int value))
{
    // value contains an int parsed out of input
}
else
{
    // parsing fails, you can do something about that, e.g. ask user for different input
}
```

Comment: I'm currently learning C# and I am trying to make a calculator and I tried to use this but it's not working so I must be doing it wrong. I'll post the code in my question

Comment: How do I fix it?